# Generating Functions and Associated Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: generating-functions, laguerre-polynomials

To give you context, I am currently attempting to derive the radial wavefunctions for a hydrogenic atom, from scratch.
B.H. Bransden, C.J. Joachain - Physics of Atoms and Molecules states:

> $$U_{p}(\rho, s) = \frac{(-s)^{p} e^{-\rho s /(1-s)}}{(1-s)^{p+1}} = \sum^{\infty}_{q=p} \frac{L^{p}_{q}(\rho)}{q!} s^q ; |s|<1$$
> An explicit expression for $L_{n+l}^{2l+1} (\rho)$ is given by $$L_{n+l}^{2l+1} (\rho) = \sum^{n-l-1}_{k=0} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{[(n+l)!]^{2} \rho^{k}}{(n-l-1-k)! (2l+1+k)! k!} $$
> and is easily verified by substitution into the above with $q = n + l$ and $p=2l+1$.

I am stuck on how to verify this by substitution. Perhaps this is a naive approach but here is what I have attempted so far:

$$ U_{p}(\rho, s) =  \sum^{\infty}_{n-l-1=0} \frac{L_{n+l}^{2l+1}(\rho)}{(n+l)!} s^{n+l}  $$
Any tips on how to progress would be very helpful.

Ultimately, I would also like to obtain $L^{2l+1}_{n-l-1}({\rho})$.

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92612/finding-a-generating-function-for-the-laguerre-polynomials?newreg=8008bde217dc403499814667432f24d5) that is somewhat related to mine, but I would like to use the expressions provided in Joachim and Bransden for the moment.

Edit: Since I asked the question, I have also attempted the following:
I first plugged in the taylor expansion of $e^{\rho s/(1-s)}$ and the binomial expansion of $(1-s)^{p+1}$ into the expression, giving:

$$ \sum^{2l+1}_{b=0} \sum^{\infty}_{a=0} \frac{(-s)^{2l+1-b+a} \rho^a b! (2l+1-b)!}{a!(2l+1)!(1-s)^a} $$

Then I tried to shift the summation index from $2l+1$ to $n-l-1$, introducing a new variable $k = b + (n-3l-2)$ but I am not sure what to do from this point. I also set $ a = n-l-1 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for a nonnegative integer $p$. We can write $U_p(\rho, s)$ as a [Riordan array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riordan_array):
$$
U_p(\rho, s)=\left(\frac{1}{1-s},-\frac{s}{1-s}\right)*(s^p e^{\rho s}).
$$
The left-hand side is the column vector of the coefficients of the power series expansion of $U_p(\rho, s)$. The right-hand side is a product of a matrix and a column vector. The left factor is the lower-triangular matrix filled with the Pascal triangle with columns alternating signs. In other words,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1-s},-\frac{s}{1-s}\right)=\left[(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\right]_{n\ge k\ge 0},
$$
where $n$ is the row index and $k$ is the column index. The right factor is the column vector of the coefficients of $s^p e^{\rho s}$, i.e.
$$
\left[\frac{\rho^{k-p}\binom{k}{p}p!}{k!}\right]_{k\ge 0}.
$$

Taking the product, we see that
$$
[x^n] U_p(\rho, s)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{\rho^{k-p}\binom{k}{p}p!}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-p}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k+p}\frac{\rho^{k}}{k!},
$$
i.e.
$$
L^{p}_{n}(\rho)=\left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right]U_p(\rho, s)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-p}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k+p}\frac{n!}{k!}\rho^{k}.
$$
Now make the substitution $n\gets n+l$, $p\gets 2l+1$.